# Spring Boot R2DBC: org.mariadb.r2dbc.client.ClientBase Connection unexpected error after an idle period

Tags: java, spring-boot, mariadb, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

hope you would help me solve the issue I am facing with MariaDB R2DBC connections in Spring Boot.

What I have in my app is consumers from RabbitMQ that on message received do some DB operations (select, insert, update etc). If relevant, RabbitMQ consuming is set according to [this example](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-rabbitmq/blob/main/reactor-rabbitmq-samples/src/main/java/reactor/rabbitmq/samples/SpringBootSample.java).

The issue is as follows.
While there is constant flow of messages from RabbitMQ (e.g. in production), everything works fine. But in other environments like testing where I send only a batch of messages via RabbitMQ after the last message is processed and after a while in idle I have these messages:

```java
2021-11-19T10:00:33.653682967Z 2021-11-19 10:00:33.653 DEBUG 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] o.s.r2dbc.core.DefaultDatabaseClient     : Executing SQL statement [<statement>]
<in a while...>
2021-11-19T10:09:28.791777463Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.790 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] org.mariadb.r2dbc.client.ClientBase      : Connection unexpected error

2021-11-19T10:09:28.791865848Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.791870296Z io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.791873532Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.792070449Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.791 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

2021-11-19T10:09:28.792084305Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.792087892Z reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.792091288Z Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.792094454Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912384320Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.911 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] org.mariadb.r2dbc.client.ClientBase      : Connection unexpected error

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912429916Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912436338Z io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912441508Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912597929Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.912 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912614901Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912620521Z reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912625822Z Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.912630660Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913520271Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.913 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] org.mariadb.r2dbc.client.ClientBase      : Connection unexpected error

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913545226Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913606432Z io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913618294Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913657416Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.913 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913670891Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913675690Z reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913680880Z Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.913685749Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914072671Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.913 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] org.mariadb.r2dbc.client.ClientBase      : Connection unexpected error

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914162960Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914175483Z io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914182827Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914310485Z 2021-11-19 10:09:28.914 ERROR 1 --- [tor-tcp-epoll-2] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914350279Z 

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914355910Z reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914379684Z Caused by: io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer

2021-11-19T10:09:28.914384694Z 

2021-11-19T10:11:00.001676921Z 2021-11-19 10:11:00.000  INFO 1 --- [   scheduling-1] c.e.d.r.service.DeviceWakeupScheduler    : Checking some stuff at 2021-11-19T10:11:00.000878682

2021-11-19T10:11:00.005672948Z 2021-11-19 10:11:00.005  WARN 1 --- [undedElastic-18] c.e.d.r.service.DeviceWakeupScheduler    : Resetting some stuff failed due to error: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcNonTransientResourceException: Connection validation failed

2021-11-19T10:11:00.009277315Z 2021-11-19 10:11:00.008 ERROR 1 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

2021-11-19T10:11:00.009290410Z 

2021-11-19T10:11:00.009294377Z org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Failed to obtain R2DBC Connection; nested exception is io.r2dbc.spi.R2dbcNonTransientResourceException: Connection validation failed

2021-11-19T10:11:00.009298164Z  at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.lambda$getConnection$0(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:88) ~[spring-r2dbc-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]

2021-11-19T10:11:00.009302392Z  at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$31(Mono.java:3732) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]

2021-11-19T10:11:00.009320226Z  at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.4.11.jar!/:3.4.11]
...
```

Here is how I connect to DB & configure server:

```
server:
  port: 8180
  netty:
    connection-timeout: 60m // added later trying to fix
    
spring:
  r2dbc:
    url: r2dbc:mariadb://<stage_ip>:3306/<database_name>
    username: <user>
    password: <password>
    pool:
      max-idle-time: 60m
      enabled: true
```

and here are some of dependencies versions I have in the project:

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.5.6</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.mariadb</groupId>
<artifactId>r2dbc-mariadb</artifactId>
<version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
<artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
<version>0.8.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: No, most likely it is somewhere in the R2DBC driver for MariaDB because I have no such issues with PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. You are probably right. There is actually a related bug report: https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-pool/issues/107
For me, retry connecting does the trick, strangely always after three times ... however.